# How to display specific custom post on click

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

i want to know how to display specific custom post - for your information i have register custom post type in wordpress dashboard panel and i have also created single-news.php file in root directory then all step has done regardless of its posts are not visible, can you pls let me know what should i do?

```
 <?php
            // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => '1'));

            // The Loop
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 post_img">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 post_content">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>



            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: You need specific one post only with news post type right?

Comment: i have many posts but i want when we click any post then post will display in single page.

Comment: As par default structure wp works like same when we click on any post or custom post it will display in single page, But if you want to create custom single file for custom post type then you have to create file with single-{post_slug}.php

Comment: Hi Kushal, i have already created single-news.php file

Comment: oK so what was the issue ? Can you elaborate with any example or anything so get some idea.

Comment: When i click any post, post is not open it just redirect on same page!

Comment: should i add any other file like - archive-news.php or something else ?

Comment: Ok on above code i did not see any link you added in your query so please put this line instead of only title 
<h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

Comment: I have add this code but still same issue i am facing.

Comment: Try to flush settings > permalinks once. And check that again

Comment: Kushal, its working but generate another issue - fatching same contents when we click different posts

Comment: ca you share  archive-news.php

Comment: Please share your single-news.php file or code.

Comment: i am trying to send but its too long char, how can i share with you?

Comment: <?php
    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => '1'));
    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
   ?>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 post_img">
     <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 post_content">
     <h2><a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
       <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

Comment: Do one thing remove this single-news.php file, Then copy and paste single.php and rename it single-news.php Then refresh your page and try

Comment: Also this code is not for single.php file this is just getting post so you have to create 1 template and put this code on that template. If it helps please up vote the answer. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Kushal, your suggestion is very helpful.